# SVG font-weight changes when rendered in html

Tags: fonts, vector, svg, html, font-weight

I have a logo in SVG format that I am using on a UI Prototype I'm creating using HTML5. I created the SVG using Inkscape. Today I noticed the logo's font-weight has changed, and I can't seem to change it back. I've been using this logo for months without an issue. I'm not sure if newly added CSS could be changing it, but when I inspect the logo using Chrome's Developer Tools (F12), there does not seem to be CSS changing it.

If I open the SVG in an HTML page by itself, its font-weight is off (too bold). I am able to target the specific text and remove the font-weight property. This fixes my issue, but I can not seem to target the text of the logo when I'm using it on my Prototype pages.

This seems to be a very similar issue, but since I'm using Inkscape and a newbie to vectors, I wasn't able to use this solution: [Preserving font type in illustrator SVG file](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27238/preserving-font-type-in-illustrator-svg-file)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was in search of. The Inkscape equivalent to "Expanding the text" is "Object to Path (CTRL + SHIFT + C). I used this command for all text in the logo, saved, and it renders correctly in my HTML now.

Comment: Yes, for logos, you shouldn't rely on the text being rendered with the proper typeface. They should always be converted to outlines to make sure it's reliably reproduced elsewhere.